# How does Roy learn Guan Yin's name?

Tags: plot-explanation, boss-level

In the movie, ***Boss Level***, a sword-wielding Guan Yin will have a pose and say a line 'I am Guan Yin and Guan Yin has done this' every time right after cutting off Roy's head.

How does Roy possibly learn Guan Yin's name if his head has been cut off before Guan Yin says her name?

It could as well be 4th-wall breaking, but from the plot and the logical point of view, how is that possible?

Comment: Does Guan Yin kill Roy in different alternate universes, or does she kill Roy over and over again in one universe?  If Guan Yin kills Roy in the same alternate universe every time, Roy must come back to life, and possibly the revived Roy remembers what she says right after cutting off his head, perhaps before even a normal persons decapited head would loose consciouness.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, it is crazy to think about a cut-off head can still hear things. I heard rumours there was a doctor that asked criminals to blink their eyes if they can still hear him after beheading. Not sure the origin of this story though.